# Changing the layout when creating a TGZ archive

Tags: cmake, build-system, cpack

I use CMake to manage a project with the following layout:

```
ProjectA/
  include
  doc
  test
ProjectB
  include
  doc
  test
```

I would like to use CPack to package up a `tar.gz` **source** archive with the following layout:

```
include/
ProjectA/
  doc
  test
ProjectB/
  doc
  test
```

where the new top-level include contains all include files.

I tried achieving this by running a CMake script through `CPACK_INSTALL_SCRIPT`, but this script runs before the files are created. Where can I hook into CPack to get that effect?

It also seems that `install` has no influence on what `make
package_source` does, but it has an effect on `make
package`. Unfortunately `make package` will also build and package
libraries, which is something I don't want to happen. I want a pure
source distribution ala `make dist`.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what the problem is. Like arrowdodger says: You should add an install() call with a DESTINATION and CPack should pick it up and correctly merge the folders. Did you try running 'CPack -G TGZ' directly, or did you use 'make package'? What happens if you specify 'projectA/include/*.h' or perhaps GLOB the sources first?

Comment: @Andre As I said: `package_source` ignores the `DESTINATION` of `install`. `package` honors it, but also tries to compile my libraries, which I don't want. I always tried `cmake package` and `cmake package_source` never `cpack` directly.

Comment: And if you accept that 'package' compiles your libraries, does it give you the correct layout?

Comment: After answering, I just noticed that you are specifically looking at the source package creation. Please update your question to make this clearer.

Comment: @JohannesS. I tried making it clearer and added why the obvious approaches fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `install(DIRECTORY include DESTINATION include)` on headers from both `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` and install them into the same dir. This would cause CPack to place them together in the generated package.

**Update**

Okay, i've managed to do this with `CPACK_INSTALL_SCRIPT` variable.

I've created following script:

```
set(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR @CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR@)

execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/A/ ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/B/ ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove_directory ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/A)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove_directory ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/B)
```

In the `CMakeLists.txt` i've populated it with actual value of `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`:

```
configure_file(CPackScript.cmake CPackScript.cmake @ONLY)
```

Finally, i've added `set(CPACK_INSTALL_SCRIPT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CPackScript.cmake)` and voila! Generated packages now have `include` dir with headers from both `A/` and `B/`, while `A/` and `B/` dirs don't exist.

Comment: I'm already doing that. It is not working. I can't seem to get the `DESTINATION` option of `install` to have any effect on `tgz` creation. I can even reproduce it with a small example case.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4360633 This will result in the same layout with `make package_source`.

Comment: What are you getting in the generated package? Empty `include` dir? Or there is even no `include` dir? Could it be that `/build*/` ignore pattern clashes with your build dir and it confuses CPack?

Comment: I end up with exactly the same layout as in the original. Funnily, if I do a `make package` the folders are merged, but this also packages up the compiled libraries. All I want is a portable `make dist` that merges a few directories.

Comment: Sorry? This is what the code already does? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Okay, i've reproduced it, somewhat. I see files only from `ProjectA`, not `ProjectB`. Is it what are you seeing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21575/discussion-between-pmr-and-arrowdodger)

Comment: Oh, in my experiments `CPACK_INSTALL_SCRIPT` is run before the source dir is populated. You should also just use `file(MAKE_DIRECTORY` when you are inside `CMake`. No need for execute process. I will try this and come back with the results.

Comment: I went for this answer because it already provides the work-around for creating the CMake script with variables and for the other possible solutions provided by arrowdodger.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible approach is to completely bypass CPack for the generation of the TGZ archive and simply use a CMake custom target which generates the archive:

```
project (MyProject)

set (DIST_TEMP_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dist")
make_directory(${DIST_TEMP_DIR})

add_custom_target(dist 
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove_directory "${DIST_TEMP_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ProjectA/include" "${DIST_TEMP_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/include"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ProjectA/test" "${DIST_TEMP_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/ProjectA/test"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ProjectA/doc" "${DIST_TEMP_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/ProjectB/doc"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ProjectB/include" "${DIST_TEMP_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/include"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ProjectB/doc" "${DIST_TEMP_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/ProjectA/doc"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ProjectB/test" "${DIST_TEMP_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/ProjectB/test"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar cvz "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.tar.gz"  "${DIST_TEMP_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/"
    COMMENT "Building ${PROJECT_NAME}.tar.gz"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${DIST_TEMP_DIR}"
)
```

The custom target `dist` first sets up the desired structure of the archive in a temporary directory inside the build folder by invoking CMake in command mode with multiple `copy_directory` commands. Then it generates the `tar.gz` archive by using the `tar` command mode sub-command.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I need to run more complicated commands including loops so this is not really feasible anymore. Launching another cmake script through the custom target sucks because you cannot load a cache this way. I can of course generate the script with the right variables set, but we are quickly approaching the hack threshold.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what excactly is not working for you.

This is what works for me for the ZIP generator on windows. I will try to find a linux machine to see if this works with TGZ as well (EDIT: it does):

Directory structure:

```
CMakeLists.txt
ProjectA/
    doc
        foo.txt
    include
        foo.h
    test
        foo.test
ProjectB/
    doc
        bar.txt
    include
        bar.h
    test
        bar.test
```

ProjectA/CMakeLists.txt

```
project( ProjectA )

INSTALL( DIRECTORY include DESTINATION . )
INSTALL( DIRECTORY doc DESTINATION ${PROJECT_NAME}/ )
INSTALL( DIRECTORY test DESTINATION ${PROJECT_NAME}/ )
```

ProjectB/CMakeLists.txt

```
project( ProjectB )

INSTALL( DIRECTORY include DESTINATION . )
INSTALL( DIRECTORY doc DESTINATION ${PROJECT_NAME}/ )
INSTALL( DIRECTORY test DESTINATION ${PROJECT_NAME}/ )
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
project( MyProject )

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(ProjectA)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(ProjectB)

INCLUDE(CPack)
```

If I create the package, I get

```
MyProject-0.1.1-win32.zip
    MyProject-0.1.1-win32
        include
            bar.h
            foo.h
        ProjectA
            doc
                foo.txt
            test
                foo.test
        ProjectB
            doc
                bar.txt
            test
                bar.test
```

Is that what you intended?

**Source packages**

For source package creation, CPack by default ignores the install commands and installs/copies all directories that are specified in `CPACK_SOURCE_INSTALLED_DIRECTORIES`. This variable contains pairs of source and destination directories. It defaults to `"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR};/"` if not manually set. To be precise, it globs these directories, ignoring all files in `CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES` which defaults to all major VCS bookkeeping files (see your `CPackSourceConfig.cmake` for example).

You you ***could*** do the following:

CMakeLists.txt

```
project( MyProject )

SET( PROJECTS ProjectA ProjectB )

SET(CPACK_SOURCE_INSTALLED_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR};/") 
FOREACH( p ${PROJECTS} ) 
    ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( ${p} )
    LIST( APPEND CPACK_SOURCE_INSTALLED_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR/${p}/include include )
ENDFOREACH()


INCLUDE(CPack)
```

or add the manipulation to of `CPACK_SOURCE_INSTALLED_DIRECTORIES` to the respective project files.

**However**: This will install your include directories to the top-level include directory, but additionally still create another copy inside the project directories due to globbing. You could probably create additional directory-pairs for your `doc` and `test` directories and skip the initialization of the `CPACK_SOURCE_INSTALLED_DIRECTORIES` in the `SET` command. If you do this, you will need to find a way to install/copy your project-specific CMake files.

**BIG CAVEAT**: If `ProjectA`or `ProjectB` refer to the project-local include directory (eg. with `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(...)` you will break your CMake code, rendering the source installation (partially) useless. So you might want to rethink your idea of the top-level include directory.

Comment: With respect to the local includes: The CMake system is set up to detect if package local or top-level includes are used already. It is just the packaging step I'm trying to change.

Comment: I don't understand (might be missing s.th.). If ProjectA's CMakeLists.txt contians `include_directories( include )` and s.b. wants to use your source package to build your software, the includes will not be found because they are now in `../include`, right?

Comment: After finding all packages the build-system checks if top-level includes are present and then sets a global variable with all include directories (including libraries that all projects depend on). This variable is used by the sub-projects to set the include path.

Comment: Ah, I see, this is specific to your system. In our setup, we actually use macros that add the project-specific include dirs to those projects that require them. Anyway, am I correct that the only missing part would now be the copying of the project-specific CMakeLists.txt? Or what else is missing in my solution?

Comment: I'll give your solution a try tomorrow and let you know. Sorry, Christmas is slowing down things. Bad idea to hand out a bounty during this time.

Comment: BTW: Eric Noulard posted on the  CMake mailing list (although nearly 2 years ago): " My summarized opinion is that if ones wants some clean feature to
package 'source' then this must be designed from the ground-up knowing current CPack behavior.

Current source packaging is more or less a hack.
Useful hack, but a hack." (http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-January/041870.html)